# Can I create a bar chart that compares to target or quota?

Tags: reporting

Is it possible to create a Bar chart on closed opptys, that will also have a value axis (or line or other format) that can be compared to either the user/division quota/target?

Answer (score 2):

Create a separate Opportunity recordtype called "Quota", then you can set quotas by populating the Amount field on these Opportunities.

Your report will summarize Amount, grouped by Record Type, and you will see performance against quota/target.

Good luck,

Jeremy

Comment: Create a single Quota oppty per person/period?  interesting. Have you tried it?  How does the forecasting/quota is related here?

Comment: I have done this before successfully in multiple organizations. Each time we tried to implement Salesforce Forecasting, and found it wasn't flexible enough to cover our needs. Unfortunately, it doesn't play with the standard forecasting at all, which may be a problem if you're already invested in that structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a few ways.

1. Standard SFDC Dashboards and Reporting per Jeremy's statement above. This is simplest approach and always use declaritive before you go into VF / code. You could create a report like Jeremey states above. That report could then feed a SFDC Dashboard of type Bar Chart.
2. Visualforce Charting (Pilot Feature) - In VF Page you could use VF Charting to accomplish this. This is feature in Beta and would require you to use SOQL, VF, and Apex to slice and dice the data, then present it in a BarChart VF Component.
3. Visualforce with Google Charts / 3rd Party Javascript - You can use 3rd party javascript charting tools in compination with VF and SOQL to generate this type of data.